# $a\cdot{b} = a^Tb$ proof

Tags: matrices, vectors

I am preparing for an in-class quiz and have stumbled upon the following chapter exercise:

Prove that $a\cdot b = a^Tb$

How do I go about proving that the dot product of two column vectors $a$ and $b$ is equal to the product $a$ transpose $b$?

Comment: Did you try looking at the definitions of dot product and matrix product and applying them to your case? (Depending on how much detail is required, you may have to use induction on the vector length.)

Comment: You have not given much context. I would say it follows immediately from the definitions of matrix product and the usual dot product.

Comment: I'm not sure how one would go about proving this, because $a \cdot b$ is usually **defined** to be $a^Tb$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a,b\in \mathbb{R}^n$.  By the definition of the dot product
$$a\cdot{b}=a_1b_1+...+a_nb_n$$

Now, by definition of matrix multiplication, since $a^T$ is a $1\times{n}$ matrix and $b$ is an $n\times{1}$ matrix, the product $a^Tb$ is a $1\times{1}$ matrix whose product is
$$a^Tb=[a_1b_1+...+a_nb_n]=a_1b_1+...+a_nb_n$$
Thus $a\cdot{b}=a^Tb$